# Delphi to Excel - Date Format Issue with German Locale

Tags: delphi, excel, datetime

Using **Delphi 2007** - **Windows 7** - **German(Switzerland) locale**.
In my application, I'm displaying a DateTime field with Displayformat as `"MMM-YY"`.
Date `3-Mar-11` is displayed as `Mai-11`.

When exporting to Excel, application first writes grid data to `TXT` file and then imports it to Excel using `OpenText()` API.
Then we apply the grid properties to the cells. Thus, the date column in Excel is applied a `NumberFormat = MMM-YY (custom format)`.
But, in Excel date is displayed as `"Mai-YY"`, because in German the date format in Excel is `MMM-JJ`.

How do I apply the correct date format from Delphi OR correct Excel behaviour so that I can have a solution across all locales?

Comment: Solution 1: apply grid properties that depends on the locale format (i.e. MMM-JJ for German). Solution 2: apply number format through vba (will use english letters to apply the format)

Answer (score 4):

Excel and dates are a bit of a muddle. If you stick to using an intermediate file, then you are probably stuck. Excel uses its own date format settings and they may/will differ from the Windows' date format settings. So even if you export using the Windows locale settings, Excel may not behave as expected when it is using a different set of values.

Using automation you can interrogate Excel for its settings.

**General recipe for exporting dates to Excel**

Be aware of the characters used in Windows date and time settings.

```
WindowsYearCharacter: string = 'y';   // Do no localize!
WindowsMonthCharacter: string = 'm';  // Do no localize!
WindowsDayCharacter: string = 'd';    // Do no localize!
WindowsHourCharacter: string = 'h';   // Do no localize!
WindowsMinuteCharacter: string = 'm'; // Do no localize!
```

Please note that the Month and minute character are both a 'm', though for dates it should be uppercased. This is needed when you have a format string that takes both a date and a time. As we export either dates or times, we opted to cater for case-insensitive specification of Windows formats.

Interrogate Excel for its xlYearCode, xlMonthCode, xlDayCode, xlHourCode and xlMinuteCode formatting characters using the International collection.

```
ExcelDayChar := ExcelApplication.International[xlDayCode];
```

Convert your Windows locale settings to use the Excel characters.

```
ExcelDateFormat := ConvertWindowsLocalDateStringToExcel(ShortDateFormat);
```

This uses the function following below. Please note again that this function can only be used for *either* a date format or a time format. Adapt as necessary when you need formats combining both date and time.

```
function ConvertWindowsLocalDateStringToExcel(const aString: string): string;
begin
  // Year character vervangen :
  Result := StringReplace(aString, UpperCase(WindowsYearCharacter), UpperCase(ExcelYearCharacter), [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, LowerCase(WindowsYearCharacter), LowerCase(ExcelYearCharacter), [rfReplaceAll]);

  // Month character vervangen :
  Result := StringReplace(Result, UpperCase(WindowsMonthCharacter), UpperCase(ExcelMonthCharacter), [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, LowerCase(WindowsMonthCharacter), LowerCase(ExcelMonthCharacter), [rfReplaceAll]);

  // Day character vervangen :
  Result := StringReplace(Result, UpperCase(WindowsDayCharacter), UpperCase(ExcelDayCharacter), [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, LowerCase(WindowsDayCharacter), LowerCase(ExcelDayCharacter), [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

Then export your data to Excel and then set the number format for the columns (or rows, or cells) containing dates to use the ExcelDateFormat you determined earlier.

```
aRange.NumberFormat := ExcelDateFormat;
```

Where aRange is (an OleVariant with an) Excel Range type.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here, and the best solution I found was to declare the cell (or range) as text before you insert the date:

Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Range['A'+inttostr(row),'M'+inttostr(row)].NumberFormat := '@';
where row is a variable of my cycle, which also use to enter data in excel